# What's honor for?

Tags: league-of-legends

The FAQ page at League of Legends.com is broken and clicking the FAQ links does nothing.

League recently brought honor into play. You can be awarded honor for several different reasons after playing a game.
What is the significance of my honor total?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of patch 7.13, the [Honor system has been updated](https://www.bing.com/search?q=honor+system+lol&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN)! It now has a significantly different purpose, as well as some worthwhile rewards.

There are 6 levels of Honor (levels 0 to 5). Everyone automatically starts at Honor level 2. Whenever you gain Honor points (detailed below), you will make progress towards the next level of Honor. At level 2, you'll receive a few key fragments every couple days. Once you level up, key fragments become more frequent. In addition, you can start earning "capsules", which contain not only key fragments but also champion and skin shards. You even have a chance at getting the now Honor-exclusive Medieval Twitch and Grey Warwick skins from these capsules. Additionally, there will be end of season rewards for people who reached the highest level of Honor.

If you are ever punished (chat restriction, ban, etc.), your Honor level will go down to level 0. Once you're at Honor level 0, you will receive no rewards at all (no key fragments). If you play nice and earn your Honor back, at level 1 you'll start earning a handful of rewards (some key fragments, but still significantly less than Honor 2). If you end the season at level 0 or 1, you will be disqualified from getting any ranked rewards such as loading screen borders or Victorious skins.

So how do you earn Honor points? Anytime you play a matchmade game (which is pretty much every game mode except custom games), you will be shown an honor screen immediately after the conclusion of the game. On this screen, you can choose one person on your team to commend in one of three categories: "Tilt-proof" (stayed calm and friendly even in tense moments), "Great Shotcalling" (did a good job helping the team maintain focus on objectives), and "GG <3" (an all-around fun player to play with). Whenever you earn a commendation from another teammate, you gain a small amount of Honor points. But don't worry if you don't get many commendations - you will still earn small amounts of passive Honor exp for every game you play, regardless of commendations. Additionally, if everyone on the team offered commendations, everyone on your team will also get an additional boost of points.

You can read more details about the new Honor system on the [wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Honor).

Answer (score 25):

According to this [site](http://www.surrenderat20.net/2012/10/psa-honor-rewards.html) and the [Honor FAQ](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/honor) which I got most of my information from.

There are four types of honor:

- **Helpful** - There are those summoners who have the know-how to help you
  step up your game and are always willing to share. If one of your
  teammates makes you feel like you’re attending a master class on
  League of Legends, be sure to recognize him for being a helpful
  teammate.
- **Friendly** - Ever meet one of those summoners who – win or lose – is
  just a pleasure to play with? This acknowledgement goes out to those
  unsung heroes of the Fields of Justice whose friendly demeanor keeps
  everyone having a good time even when the chips are down.
- **Teamwork** - Some players really put the needs of the team over their
  personal interests. These players lead the way on the Fields of
  Justice, support struggling teammates, and are always the first to
  step up and select a role the team needs. This acknowledgement is for
  all those players who understand that a chain is only as strong as
  its weakest link.
- **Honorable Opponent** - Sometimes you run into an opponent who is humble
  in victory and graceful in defeat. Be sure to acknowledge those
  adversaries who embody the spirit of sportsmanship as Honorable
  Opponents.

You currently get some profile indicators, as well as other bonuses.

The profile indicator: (Icons left to right are: Friendly , Helpful , Teamwork , Honorable Opponent)

[image: profile indicator]

First bonus for getting that you are a great teammate is this during champion select:

[image: Great Teammate]

Same thing but for being an honorable opponent

[image: honorable opponent]

These also show up during the loading screen

[image]

The popup once you are alerted that you have received one of these alerts

[image: popup]

Right now the exact amount of times you need to be honored is unknown. This is more then likely due to the honor votes being weighted in the background. Someone who honors just their friends votes count less then random people you play in matchmaking.

Right now the only way to loose honor is if you are reported to the Tribunal and found guilty of of a infraction. This resets all your honor to zero.

Comment: I hope they can eventually leverage the honor system to match up players of equal honor. I'd rather play with friendly and cooperative teammates than your average arse, even if it means losing a few more games.

Comment: @toNyldaS: Cue sock puppets who 'honor' griefers so they can gatecrash ur little honorable party ...

Comment: Adding on to everyone else, I found that the maybe required amount of honor for the first "badge" is about 15. The badge cannot be seen by the player (or maybe that is just me) but can be seen by the opponents and your teammates. Or I really can't see the badge. Does anyone know a way to find it?

Comment: @Alok ideally they wouldn't last as being punished by the tribunal removes your honor

Comment: @toNyldaS People with honor constitute at best 4% of the population. They'd be a small group, and queue times would be much longer. I like to think of them as model players, rather than the average player. These are the people who go out of their way to make sure you have a good game.

Comment: @Andrew I think that's largely untrue, unless it's a coincidence that 50% of the players in any given game I've played have the honorable opponent tag.

Comment: @SadlyNot The numbers have probably increased significantly since honor was first implemented--I got the numbers from a Riot post.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, all it does is display on your profile indicators about how your fellow players and your opponents see you. Do they find you friendly? Helpful? A good teammate? Until Riot Games is sure that the honor system is working as intended, they won't make it good for anything, but when their FAQ is up it says that they are considering options for giving players bonuses for high honor in the future.

Comment: It also appears in the character selection screen for that player. I was playing some games last nite in ranked and saw some people with an icon next to their name with a tooltip telling me that they were recognized by the community as honorable opponents.

Comment: @halfwarr thats interesting, ive never seen this. I wonder how much honor you have to have for it to show

Comment: @ender added more information about in my own post