# How much honor must I have to earn badges?

Tags: league-of-legends

I see in this [earlier question about honor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86811/whats-honor-for) that the amount needed is unknown, but [in another question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89958/how-do-i-get-the-honor-banners) it's stated to be 25.

How much **Teamplay** or **Honorable Opponent** honor must I earn to receive a badge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no hard number known to receive the honor ribbons.

Per the [LoL wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Honor#Crests_and_Ribbons):

> Please note that there are currently no specifics given by RiotGames
>   regarding the exact numbers or formulas used in order to award medals
>   and ribbons to honorable summoners, though there are rumors 100 Honor
>   Points are needed for Friendly, Helpful and Teamwork Ribbons and 30
>   for the Honorable Opponent Ribbon, although it is confirmed to be
>   possible to get the teamwork ribbon without 100 Honor Points.

Comment: There is no flat number. [@MonochromaticPalette's answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/92838/115693) should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 15):

The Honor Ribbon is not based on the quantity of Honor Points you have.

**It is based on the consistency in which you get Honor.**

Basically, your **honor per game** in a certain section is what determines whether or not you get an Honor Badge/Ribbon.

There are a few other variables that screw around with this value; most surround how many times you have played with/against the person honoring you. You will most likely get more out of a stranger honoring you, rather than a regular duo-queue friend. *If you want to gain an Honor Badge, avoid 5-man queues.*

Having 25 or 100 were just a few of the false beliefs regarding honor when it was first announced.

*There is no way* to find out how many honor you've had per game so far. On a side note, if you are **punished** by the Tribunal for wrongdoings, your honor is **reset to 0**; your honor per game, therefore, is reset to 0 as well.

I hope this helped you!

Comment: Why do you mean about "*If you want to gain an Honor Badge, avoid 5-man queues.*" ?

Comment: @Michel he means if you play 5-man queues, you will be getting honor from your friends instead of strangers, which isn't as valuable.